# find the value of the sumation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

find the value of the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{-n^2}}{ \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k^2}}}=\infty$$
a) $0$

b) $some c ∈ (0,1)$

c) 1

d) ∞

this is the orginial questions
[image]

from my thinking  the answer  will be ∞

Comment: Please improve formatting and add some actual attempt. The outcome is clear from the Stolz-Cesàro theorem, for instance.

Comment: not getting @JackD'Aurizio,,can u elaborate more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we try to bound $\frac{2^{-n^2}}{ \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{-k^2}}}$, We know that:$$\frac{2^{-n^2}}{ \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} {2^{-k^2}}}=\frac{1}{ \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} {2^{n^2-k^2}}}=\frac{1}{2^{-2n-1}+2^{-4n-4}+2^{-6n-9}+...}>\frac{1}{2^{-2n}+2^{-4n}+2^{-6n}+...}=\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{4})^{n}+(\frac{1}{4})^{2n}+(\frac{1}{4})^{3n}+...}=\frac{1}{\frac{(\frac{1}{4})^{n}}{1-(\frac{1}{4})^{n}}}=4^n-1$$
then tending $n\to\infty $ leads us to: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{-n^2}}{ \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{-k^2}}}=\infty$$

Comment: thanks a lots Mostafa Ayaz

Comment: what u mean...?

Comment: @ Mostafa Ayaz  acoording to the orginal question,,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{-n^2}}{ \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k^2}}}=\infty$$..is it correct ? ..as i have written the question some - sign mistakes

Comment: Yes i'm sorry for wrong comments...

Comment: ok  no problem,,as  edit  the answer as   see  my orginal question photo,,,i would be grateful if u edit the answer

Comment: How do i edit the answer?

Comment: i mean ur  answer is correct or not,,according to my orginal question/photo?  as i tried  $$\frac{2^{-n^2}}{ \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{+k^2}}}=\frac{1}{ \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n^2+k^2}}}$$,,can not  proceed  further....

Comment: You should write $\frac{1}{\sum{2^{n^2-k^2}}}$ here is ur mistake

Comment: ok got it ,,once again thanks  alot @ Mostafa Ayaz